# notify specific person using io.to(user).emit()

Tags: typescript, socket.io

I am using socket.io to manage user online offline. and I need to notify a specific user when another user is offline. Please help me out of these
`UserOnline` manages when user comes online, or the user goes offline.

Here is the code

```
socket.on("Online", function(UserOneID, UserTwoID) {
    var UserOne = UserOnline.find(f => f.UserId == UserOneID);
    var UserTwo = UserOnline.find(f => f.UserId == UserTwoID);
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(UserTwo)) {
        io.to(UserOne).emit("Success", "User" + UserTwo + " is online now");    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to store the first socket.Id with UserID in array. while user connect first and when you want to use emit please review code below

```
io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('Connection', 'Hey, How are you');
```